# oras: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client

Tags: registry, oci

I use the [oras](https://oras.land/) cli to upload oci artifacts.

I get:

```
❯ oras push 127.0.0.1:5000/foo/test:is --artifact-type application/vnd.foo content             
Error: Head "https://127.0.0.1:5000/v2/foo/test/manifests/sha256:...": 
http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client
```

Roughly the same command worked fine with ghcr.io

What could be wrong?

I tried this, but now I get:

```
❯ oras  push   http://127.0.0.1:5000/foo/test:is --artifact-type application/vnd.foo content
Error: invalid reference: invalid repository
```

How to upload to my local registry?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the flag `--plain-http`, then it works:

```
❯ oras  push --plain-http  127.0.0.1:5000/foo/test:is --artifact-type application/vnd.foo content
Uploading b5bb9d8014a0 content
Uploaded  b5bb9d8014a0 content
Pushed [registry] 127.0.0.1:5000/foo/test:is
Digest: sha256:...
```